# Cannot find -lsrc (gcc compilation failure)

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to build a C++ project in Netbeans and in the output console I am having the below compilation error that results from a missing file named -lsrc  (marked with ###)

I am using Suse Linux (SLED 11) and does anyone know what package I should download in the package installer so that I can overcome this gcc compilation issue?

```
g++ -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cppthriftserverv1 
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/1338215927/test_types.o -lsrc 

#### HERE ####
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../i586-suse-linux/bin/ld: 
 cannot find -lsrc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
#### HERE #####

gmake[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cppthriftserverv1] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/home/TRYOUT/THRIFT/CPPSERVER/CPPServerProject/CPPThriftServerV1'
gmake[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/home/TRYOUT/THRIFT/CPPSERVER/CPPServerProject/CPPThriftServerV1'
gmake: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 614ms)
```

Comment: farda: please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts - salutations should not be added in your posts here. And if you do revert an edit, at least try and conserve the formatting that was added.

Comment: Your distro does not have a package search functionality?

Comment: I searched for this thing named "lsrc" in YAST but it does not return anything. Googling does not return much info either. I think I need to know the the name of the encapsulating package to search for  the correct thing.

Comment: @farda: Where did you find that you needed to add `-lsrc`? Doesn't that documentation tell you what library it comes from/requires?

Comment: YAST has a functionality allowing to search in the available package repositories based on an ordinary keyword. In case it cannot find st, it simply says no result found and no clue about some other possible repositories that can include this lsrc is given. YAST is the preferred way to install packages in Suse linux (SLED) as far as I know.

Comment: Googling `lib/libsrc.so` gives me only obscure results from an IBM page which won't even show. Try to remove `-lsrc` from the command and try again. It can also be a library aspecially make for this project (in which case, check if it exists in some folder).

Comment: The thing is the build and linking is done by the netbeans IDE and so far I could not find a trace on the root cause of this issue in the IDE generated configuration files. Do you have any idea on where to look in the IDE for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the IDE tries to link against some library in the src folder of your project. Do you include a library in the source code? You can creating a Makefile so you can try compiling from the console and see the errors from the compiler.